# Were pipelines removed from akka i/o?

Tags: java, tcp, akka, pipeline, akka-io

While learning how to use akka I/O I am trying to implement a simple protocal on top of akka i/o and was following the documentation [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/java/io-codec.html).

However in my gradle file I use version 2.3.9 as shown below

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.7'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: 'akka-actor_2.11', version: '2.3.9'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: 'akka-contrib_2.11', version: '2.3.9'
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.11.5'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

import of some things that are pipeline specific like

```
import akka.io.SymmetricPipelineStage;
import akka.io.PipelineContext;
import akka.io.SymmetricPipePair;
```

generate can not resolve symbol errors.

Hence my questions.

1. Were these removed or there is some dependancy I need to add to my gradle file.
2. If they were removed, how would the encod/decode stage be dealt with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipelines were experimental and indeed removed in Akka 2.3.
The removal was documented in the [Migration Guide 2.2.x to 2.3.x](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/project/migration-guide-2.2.x-2.3.x.html#Experimental_Pipelines_IO_abstraction_has_been_removed).

There is also mention of being able to package the "older" pipeline implementation with Akka 2.3 [here](https://github.com/gideondk/sentinel#pipelines), though it doesn't appear to be a simple addition of a dependency.

I would wager that Akka Streams is intended to be the better replacement of pipelines, coming in Akka 2.4, but available now as an [experimental module](http://akka.io/docs/#akka-streams-and-http). The encode/decode stage or protocol layer can be handled by using Akka Streams in conjunction with Akka I/O.

Comment: thanks for the answer. if you don't mind could you share an example codec with the protocol layer prefferably in java built on top of akka stream?

Comment: I have some Scala code that takes raw bytes and converts them into message frames using Akka Streams in my [scalable-chat project](https://github.com/ezoerner/scalable-chat/blob/introduce-akka-streams/messaging/src/main/scala/scalable/messaging/tcp/FrameStage.scala). I don't have any sample Java code, unfortunately. The relevant section in the akka docs is at [Custom stream processing](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M5/java/stream-customize.html).

Comment: In particular a complete documentation example of layering protocols is shown [in the Akka Streams documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M5/java/stream-graphs.html#Bidirectional_Flows) (it will be highly beneficial to read all the docs and not just that section).

Comment: @RolandKuhn thanks for the pointer though I think I may be forced to stick with akka io since I would like to implement something that provides push mechanism like an xmpp server.  Is this possible with Akka streams too? In akka io I have been able to use an actor to send a message from the server to the client once connected however I can't seem to figure out how this can be done in akka streams

Comment: @Bwire Have a look at `ActorPublisher` / `ActorSubscriber`, they are meant to be the bridge between Actors and Reactive Streams: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M5/scala/stream-integrations.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pipelines were removed without any alternatives. I came from Netty world and don't find pipelines "unintuitive" - they accumulate buffers and supply children actors with ready to use messages.

Take a look at our solutions, it requires `"org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % 7.2.14` as a dependency.

Codec class is a `State` monad which is being called by the actor and produces output. In our projects we are using `Varint32 protobuf encoding`, so every message is prepended with `varint32` length field:

```
import com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream
import com.trueaccord.scalapb.{GeneratedMessage, GeneratedMessageCompanion, Message}
import com.zeptolab.tlc.front.codecs.Varint32ProtoCodec.ProtoMessage

import scalaz.{-\/, State, \/, \/-}

trait Accumulator
trait Codec[IN, OUT] {

  type Stream = State[Accumulator, Seq[IN]]

  def decode(buffer: Array[Byte]): Throwable \/ IN

  def encode(message: OUT): Array[Byte]

  def emptyAcc: Accumulator

  def decodeStream(data: Array[Byte]): Stream

}

object Varint32ProtoCodec {

  type ProtoMessage[T] = GeneratedMessage with Message[T]

  def apply[IN <: ProtoMessage[IN], OUT <: ProtoMessage[OUT]](protoType: GeneratedMessageCompanion[IN]) = new Varint32ProtoCodec[IN, OUT](protoType)

}

class Varint32ProtoCodec[IN <: ProtoMessage[IN], OUT <: ProtoMessage[OUT]](protoType: GeneratedMessageCompanion[IN]) extends Codec[IN, OUT] {

  import com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream

  private case class AccumulatorImpl(expected: Int = -1, buffer: Array[Byte] = Array.empty) extends Accumulator

  override def emptyAcc: Accumulator = AccumulatorImpl()

  override def decode(buffer: Array[Byte]): Throwable \/ IN = {
    \/.fromTryCatchNonFatal {
      val dataLength = CodedInputStream.newInstance(buffer).readRawVarint32()
      val bufferLength = buffer.length
      val dataBuffer = buffer.drop(bufferLength - dataLength)
      protoType.parseFrom(dataBuffer)
    }
  }

  override def encode(message: OUT): Array[Byte] = {
    val messageBuf = message.toByteArray
    val messageBufLength = messageBuf.length
    val prependLength = CodedOutputStream.computeUInt32SizeNoTag(messageBufLength)
    val prependLengthBuffer = new Array[Byte](prependLength)
    CodedOutputStream.newInstance(prependLengthBuffer).writeUInt32NoTag(messageBufLength)
    prependLengthBuffer ++ messageBuf
  }

  override def decodeStream(data: Array[Byte]): Stream = State {
    case acc: AccumulatorImpl =>
      if (data.isEmpty) {
        (acc, Seq.empty)
      } else {
        val accBuffer = acc.buffer ++ data
        val accExpected = readExpectedLength(accBuffer, acc)
        if (accBuffer.length >= accExpected) {
          val (frameBuffer, restBuffer) = accBuffer.splitAt(accExpected)
          val output = decode(frameBuffer) match {
            case \/-(proto) => Seq(proto)
            case -\/(_) => Seq.empty
          }
          val (newAcc, recOutput) = decodeStream(restBuffer).run(emptyAcc)
          (newAcc, output ++ recOutput)
        } else (AccumulatorImpl(accExpected, accBuffer), Seq.empty)
      }
    case _ => (emptyAcc, Seq.empty)
  }

  private def readExpectedLength(data: Array[Byte], acc: AccumulatorImpl) = {
    if (acc.expected == -1 && data.length >= 1) {
      \/.fromTryCatchNonFatal {
        val is = CodedInputStream.newInstance(data)
        val dataLength = is.readRawVarint32()
        val tagLength = is.getTotalBytesRead
        dataLength + tagLength
      }.getOrElse(acc.expected)
    } else acc.expected
  }

}
```

And the Actor is:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, Props}
import akka.event.Logging
import akka.util.ByteString
import com.zeptolab.tlc.front.codecs.{Accumulator, Varint32ProtoCodec}
import com.zeptolab.tlc.proto.protocol.{Downstream, Upstream}

object FrameCodec {
  def props() = Props[FrameCodec]
}

class FrameCodec extends Actor {

  import akka.io.Tcp._

  private val logger       = Logging(context.system, this)
  private val codec        = Varint32ProtoCodec[Upstream, Downstream](Upstream)
  private val sessionActor = context.actorOf(Session.props())

  def receive = {
    case r: Received =>
      context become stream(sender(), codec.emptyAcc)
      self ! r
    case PeerClosed => peerClosed()
  }

  private def stream(ioActor: ActorRef, acc: Accumulator): Receive = {
    case Received(data) =>
      val (next, output) = codec.decodeStream(data.toArray).run(acc)
      output.foreach { up =>
        sessionActor ! up
      }
      context become stream(ioActor, next)
    case d: Downstream =>
      val buffer = codec.encode(d)
      ioActor ! Write(ByteString(buffer))
    case PeerClosed => peerClosed()
  }

  private def peerClosed() = {
    logger.info("Connection closed")
    context stop self
  }

}
```